# Добавление строки с помощью before

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добавляю в существующую таблицу *(table)* новую строку. Нужно использовать *before*, чтобы новая строка была предпоследней.
Последняя строка с классом "last".
Новая строка "newTr".

```
$('.last').before(newTr);
```

Как мне указать что добавляться строка должна в конкретную таблицу? 
//Может что-то в роде: `(table.('.last')).before(newTr)`?

Comment: так а чем вас before не устраивает ? 
$(".last").before(newTr);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у Вас класс `last` определен у одного элемента на странице, то все будет работать. Если же у Вас есть несколько таблиц на странице и в каждой таблице есть строка с классом `last`, то тогда при выборе селектора указывайте контекст поиска

```
$('.last', table).before(newTr);
```